# Add Business Days To DateTime Where Business Days Are Configurable

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, dayofweek

I want to write the following function which adds `n` number of business days to the `DateTime`. However, I want the business days to be configurable:

```
public DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime dateTime, int n, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> businessDays)
{
    // ?
}
```

e.g. Wednesday may be a holiday, so I want to skip that day only:

```
DateTime.Today.AddBusinessDays(
    7,
    new DayOfWeek[] 
    {
        DayOfWeek.Monday,
        DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
        DayOfWeek.Thursday,
        DayOfWeek.Friday,
        DayOfWeek.Saturday,
        DayOfWeek.Sunday,
    });
```

I realize that I could write a naive implementation to look over each day but I'm looking for a better implementation.

## UPDATE

No working examples so far, here are some xUnit tests to help test the different scenarios:

```
[Theory]
// Zero Values
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 0, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", "01/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 0, "Saturday", "01/01/2016")]
// Positive Days
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 1, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", "02/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 30, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", "31/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 1, "Saturday", "02/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 2, "Saturday", "09/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 3, "Saturday", "16/01/2016")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", 7, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday", "08/01/2016")]
// Negative Days    
[InlineData("01/01/2016", -1, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", "31/12/2015")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", -31, "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", "01/12/2015")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", -1, "Saturday", "26/12/2015")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", -2, "Saturday", "19/12/2015")]
[InlineData("01/01/2016", -3, "Saturday", "12/12/2015")]
public void AddBusinessDays(string start, int days, string businessDays, string expectedEnd)
{
    var daysOfWeek = businessDays.Split(',').Select(x => (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), x));
    var actualEnd = DateTime.Parse(start).AddBusinessDays(days, daysOfWeek);
    Assert.Equal(DateTime.Parse(expectedEnd), actualEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. It uses the number of days to keep a counter and only decrements it when a configured business day is added to the date. With suggestions from [Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657110/add-business-days-to-datetime-where-business-days-are-configurable#comment64695582_38657183) I've used a HashSet to speed up lookups somewhat. It's still a very linearly scaling algorithm, however.

```
public DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime dateTime, int n, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> businessDays)
{
    var tmpDate = dateTime;

    var bdLookup = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>(businessDays); 

    while (n > 0)
    {
        tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays(1);
        if (bdLookup.Contains(tmpDate.DayOfWeek))
            n--;
    }

    return tmpDate;
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off putting the days of week into some form of HashSet, so you are not iterating all the elements - after all somebody could be adding 10,000 days to a date and thats going to get sloooow

Comment: I just tested adding 10 000 days, and it did it in 8ms. So that's pretty slow. ;)

Comment: its as easy as 2 line change `var bdLookup = new HashSet(businessDays)` and `bdLookup.Contains(tmpDate.DayOfWeek)`

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I've added it. Still slow at 4ms at 10 000 days. Adding 50 years worth of business days takes about 1ms. But... if anyone books an appointment that far ahead, they deserve the time it takes. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen As you are benchmarking this already, can you check out my variation of your answer? It’s in constant time, so it should be faster :)

Comment: Also, what if days is negative?

Answer (score 2):

Constant-time variation of [J. Steen’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38657183/216074):

```
public DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int n, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> businessDays)
{
    var days = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>(businessDays);

    // add full weeks
    date = date.AddDays(7 * n / days.Count);

    // get the remainder
    n %= days.Count;

    // add the remaining days; at most 6 times
    while (n > 0)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        if (days.Contains(date.DayOfWeek))
            n--;
    }

    return date;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Much faster. I get no result above 1ms. Not even up until almost overflowing the DateTime. Saving on those iterations is very nice. =)

Comment: The duration I get, for adding 400 000 business days, is around 00:00:00.00004. So. Tiny.

Comment: Haha :D Guess we’re done optimizing this problem then xD

Comment: What if days is negative?